# Convert long table to dataframe

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following table x:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  27748156 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ read  : chr  "P601005_295" "P601005_375" "P601005_466" "P601005_503" ...
 $ OTU   : chr  "P601005_287" "P601005_287" "P601005_287" "P601005_287" ...
 $ sample: chr  "P601005" "P601005" "P601005" "P601005" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I´m trying to convert the table into a dataframe as follows

```
 df <- as(table(x$sample,x$OTU),"matrix")
 Error in table(x$sample, x$OTU): attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a `table`, another option is `dcast` from `data.table` as it is already a `data.table` object

```
library(data.table)
dcast(x, sample ~ OTU, fun.aggregate = length)
#    sample P601005_287 P601005_288 P601005_289
#1: P601005     4626753     4624952     4624146
#2: P601008     4624542     4624074     4623689
```

---

Regarding the conversion of `table` to `data.frame`, one option is

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(x$sample, x$OTU))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
n <- 27748156
x <- data.table(OTU = sample(c("P601005_287", "P601005_288", "P601005_289"), 
    n, replace = TRUE), sample = sample(c("P601005", "P601008"), 
          n, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: @david I was using the same dimensions as you showed.  May be you need to increase memory

Comment: @david Are you able to do `x[, .(n = .N), .(sample, OTU)]` if that works, you can keep it in long format